# Merge fileReplacement attribute of two different angular configurations

Tags: angular, merge, build, config

I have a bunch of angular configuration which i use in combination with each other to make different builds but one problem I have is that the **fileReplacements** attribute of a configs are not merged and the last config given in the build command overwrites the rest of configs' attribute.

Example:

File fileReplacements of config1

```
{
     "replace": "src/app/tools/white-label.config.ts",
     "with": "src/app/tools/xyz.config.ts"
 }
```

And fileReplacements of config2

```
 {
    "replace": "src/app/config/dashboard.config.ts",
    "with": "src/app/config/manage-dashboard.config.ts"
 }
```

And when i Build with command

```
ng build --configuration=config1,config2
```

Only the replacements from config2 apply

Comment: From the docs: “ If multiple configurations change the same setting, the last-set value is the final one.”. So I guess your solution is not viable unfortunately..

Comment: Did you find a workaround? Or is the answer still "not possible."

Comment: @ahong I just wrote a node script to replace the assets after build.

Answer (score -1):

The solution would be easy:

in `~/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js`

change this section (using Angular 13 around line 150)

```js
for (const configuration of configurations) {
    options = {
        ...options,
        ...(await this.workspaceHost.getOptions(target.project, target.target, configuration)),
    };
}
```

with this

```js
for (const configuration of configurations) {
    const prevFileReplacements = options.fileReplacements || [];
    options = {
        ...options,
        ...(await this.workspaceHost.getOptions(target.project, target.target, configuration)),
    };
    options.fileReplacements = prevFileReplacements.concat(options.fileReplacements);
}
```

Comment: This change only works for your local environment, it won't work when you deploy with clear installation of packages.

Comment: I never did claim that to be the best solution. But still one that fulfills the stated task.
What you can do is, add a post-install section to your package.json to do the replacement.
Be aware though that you will have to be diligent with changes to the dependency versions as newer iterations are likely to make larger modifications.